# Converting a number from decimal numeral system to all other systems (from 2 to 16) in Java

Tags: java, numerical, data-conversion

Is there any easy way to do that without creating my own methods? I only find this:

```
static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
```

Which is told to be good only for 2, 10, 8 and 16. What about the rest?

Comment: Where did you read that it only worked for 2, 8, 10, 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt` is for converting from a string representation of a number with a particular radix, to an integer value. If you want to convert a number to a representation in a particular radix, use

```
Integer.toString(n, radix);
```

where `radix` can be anything from 2 to 36. After that we run out of letters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method:

```
Integer.toString(i, base)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)

Answer (score 3):

[`Integer.parseInt(String, radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) is not limited to any specific radix, and can handle anything between [`Character.MIN_RADIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_RADIX) (i.e., 2) and [`Character.MAX_RADIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX) (i.e., 36). It's perfectly safe to use in your usecase.